# Mixed time zones settings (windows server)

Tags: windows, server, timezone

Is there a way of setting up a server with mixed time zones settings (windows server)?

An application checks for the time signature before allowing access and I have two time-zones to check.

I have one server which I would like to split a test up on, by having two time zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You cannot set up a server to be in two time zones simultaneously.

What you can do, is to write your code to not be dependent upon the server's time zone setting.  Avoid all concepts of "local time".  Be explicit about using a particular time zone instead.  Then you can test with as many time zones as you want without changing any server settings.